# .NET Core EF + Identity with PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

so I have to migrate from SQL Server to PostgreSQL with all our .net core apps - database itself and connection with it works fine but there's a problem with how database context was used and async methods used by .NET Identity extension. I'll use our database seeder class to explain my issue.

At the moment we've had defined dbContext and Identity like this in ConfigureServices method at Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext < ApplicationDbContext > (options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

//values seeder
services.AddScoped < Seeder > ();

//http context
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

//Auth
services.AddDefaultIdentity < User > (options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles < IdentityRole > ()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores < ApplicationDbContext > ();
services.Configure < IdentityOptions > (o =>
{
    o.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    o.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    o.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    o.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
    o.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    o.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
    o.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
    o.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
});
```

and our Seeder.cs:

```
using SomeApp.Data;
using SomeApp.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SomeApp
{
    public class Seeder
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

        public Seeder(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, UserManager<User> userManager)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async Task Seed()
        {
            var roles = new[] { "Superadmin", "User" };
            
            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                if (_dbContext.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == role))
                    continue;
                
                var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(_dbContext);
            
                var r = new IdentityRole(role)
                {
                    NormalizedName = role.ToUpperInvariant()
                };
                await roleStore.CreateAsync(r);
                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            
            if (_userManager.FindByNameAsync("admin1234").Result is null)
                await CreateDefaultUser();
        }

        private async Task CreateDefaultUser()
        {
            var user = new User
            {
                Email = "admin@admin.pl",
                FirstName = "Admin",
                LastName = "Admin",
                UserName = "admin1234",
                Department = "IT",
                ImagePath = "/assets/user_icon.png",
                IsAnonimised = false,
                IsLoggedIn = true
            };

            var result = _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Test1234_").Result;
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Superadmin");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's not the prettiest (this was basically project which we used to learn .net core) but it worked with SQL Server. Case is it's no longer working with PostgreSQL because it throws an exception like this:

```
Npgsql.NpgsqlOperationInProgressException (0x80004005): The connection is already in state 'Executing'
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<StartUserAction>g__DoStartUserAction|255_0(<>c__DisplayClass255_0& )
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.StartUserAction(ConnectorState newState, NpgsqlCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean attemptPgCancellation)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.StartUserAction(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean attemptPgCancellation)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Reset(Boolean async)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.CloseAsync(Boolean async)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Close()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.CloseDbConnection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Close()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTransaction.ClearTransaction()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTransaction.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.ResetState(Boolean disposeDbConnection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at AllegroSerwis.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Work\ASPdotNETProjects\SomeApp\SomeApp\Program.cs:line 10
```

Looks like for some reason await did not paused rest of the loop until async method finished it's work and PostgreSQL can't handle multiple calls on one database context. I did some digging and most common opinion was that I should use factory pattern to create separated instances on each call instead of just one context injected everywhere. So I did:

```
//db
services.AddDbContextFactory < ApplicationDbContext > (options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

and injected factory instead of context, it worked for roles seeding loop where I can just create new db context, but not for _userManager used below - as it probably gets db context from Startup.cs and it's not defined there at the moment. Can someone please explain to me more or less what's the best practice to solve this issue and use Entity Framework + Identity + PostgreSQL together, eventually how to implement factory pattern for all of them. At this point I am frustrated beyond measure and Microsoft documentation is lacking for anything that is not SQL Server.

EDIT: Added ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: IdentityDbContext
{
    public DbSet < User > Users
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DbSet < IdentityRole > Roles
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DbSet < Summary > Summaries
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DbSet < Report > Reports
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    //report models subsets
    public DbSet < LogginData > LogginData
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DbSet < EnergyCapsules > EnergyCapsules
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DbSet < BossFightLog > BossFight
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DbSet < Interaction > Interactions
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DbSet < CustomerCall > Calls
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DbSet < Questionaire > Questionaires
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DbSet < Post > Posts
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DbSet < FaqItem > FaqItems
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions < ApplicationDbContext > options): base(options)
    {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity < User > ()
            .Property(u => u.Email)
            .IsRequired();
        builder.Entity < Role > ()
            .Property(r => r.Name)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

---

Comment: put ApplicationDbContext code also

Comment: @CodingMytra done - but it's pretty basic so I don't think it helps.

Comment: and how is your Seeder class used/called ?

Comment: In Startup.cs I inject it inside Configure method and simply call seeder.Seed();

Comment: you can check if this gets called only once or on every request, I somehow suspect that part.

Comment: It seems like it's only called once at a start, but even it wasn't there is a check before any database call.

Comment: I also changed everything there to async and added await to seeder.Seed() call in Startup.cs but now it throws: 
`System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed context instance.`

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need `await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();` because
  `RoleStore.CreateAsync()` is already do this operation.
- Do not use database access in for loops unless you have to. For this
  create list and use `_dbSet.AddRange()` overload.
- Make sure to wait async database calls.

I do the same thing you did by applying the best practices above and it works. Check out [my template](https://github.com/Milvasoft/MilvaTemplate/blob/master/Content/MilvaTemplate.API/Migrations/DataSeed.cs) for exapmle.